# Switching Toggle State On Page Appearing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin doesn't seem to natively support commanding a switch. In my app, apon a page opening, the app scans a device and looks at a certain value. Depending on whether or not the value is 0 or 1 I'd like to set the state of the switch accordingly.

I'd like it to determine and change state inside of:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
```

On Xaml page I have:

```
<Switch Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" IsToggled ="{Binding OnToggledCutouts, Mode=TwoWay}" Toggled="OnToggledCutout" x:Name="ToggleCutouts"/>
```

Implementation would ideally look something like:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    x = readDeviceValue(0)
    if (x = 1) 
    {
    OnToggledCutouts = true;
    }
    else
    {
    OnToggledCutouts = false;
    }
}
```

How can I assign a boolean value to the TwoWay binding?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on first line of that code. Step through it. You should be able to see your mistake soon enough. I’d point it out, but you need to learn to use debugger, so tell me what you discover. Or if its simply a typo in the code you put here, fix it. Either way, I’ll check back tomorrow.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Hey steve. This code is nowhere near verbatum. Coincidentally after I posted this I stumbled apon a thread from 7 years ago that answered the question. I'm supposed to be using the x:Name of the switch and not the IsToggled. Feeling pretty stupid after spending so much time on this...You're right. I should learn to use the debugger :)

Comment: Glad you solved it. It is possible to do what you tried - but more details have to be right, to get it to work. For future reference: `public bool OnToggledCutouts { get =>_onToggledCutouts; set { _onToggledCutouts = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }`. `.. OnAppearing() { ...` `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => { ...YOUR CODE ... OnToggledCutouts = true; ... });` and of course `BindingContext = ...` somewhere. You might try this code, just to see if you can get this technique to work - you'll need it someday!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the x:Name of the switch and not the IsToggled:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    x = readDeviceValue(0)
    if (x = 1) 
    {
    ToggleCutouts.IsToggled = true;
    }
    else
    {
    ToggleCutouts.IsToggled = false;
    }
}
```